# wxWidgets wxSplitterWindow floating in top left

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have been trying to add a wxSplitterWindow to a vertical wxBoxSizer like so:

```
....

wxSplitterWindow * split = new wxSplitterWindow(this, wxID_ANY);

split->SplitVertically(selectPanel, trackingPanel);

verticalBox->Add(serverBarBox, 0, wxEXPAND);
verticalBox->Add(new wxStaticText(this, wxID_ANY, _("File selector:")), 0, wxEXPAND);
verticalBox->Add(split, 1, wxEXPAND);

...
```

but this only produces results in which the wxSplitterBox floats as a tiny square in the top left of the frame. What exactly is going on here?

[image]

As you can see the top left has part of a button which is part of one of the panels im adding to the splitter window.(Note i took out the static text for this picture hence why that isn't in there, though it does display properly when not commented out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with parenting. You need to make sure that the panels are the children of the splitter window ( selectPanel and trackingPanel)

```
trackingPanel = new wxPanel(split,...);
```

You might want to consider using some kind of wxWidgets designer such as wxCrafter or wxFormBuilder

Comment: Ahhh thank you very much I was doing this instead of split for the panels. Why exactly does this need to be the case. Doesn't the splitter window take over being the parent when you do a split?

Comment: No. Unless you call to wxWindow::Reparent